Testing of "Android for Cars App Library"-Apps
So i am trying to design a small app which just reads out some data regarding the car using the CarInfo module of the "Android for Cars App Library". I did some reading on the topic and followed the codelab ( https://developer.android.com/codelabs/car-app-library-fundamentals#6 ) to learn how to use said library. However, it says in section 7 (see link):

Test in real vehicles
To test your app in real vehicles, it must be installed from a trusted source such as the Play Store, with one exception detailed in Allow unknown sources. You can use Internal App Sharing or an Internal Test Track to distribute your app to devices without going through the Play Store review process.


Allow unknown sources
On Android Auto, there is also a developer option to enable running apps not installed from a trusted source. This setting only applies to media and messaging apps and doesn't apply to apps built using the Android for Cars App Library.

So does this mean, that for every little test of every small change i make to my code, I would have to load it up to the playstore using one of the two given methods? Is there really no way at all to do this without?
Reminder, i just want to read out some data, i.e. make and model or fuel consumption or alike, nothing fancy, just data gathering.
Or is there a completely different possible approach to read the current fuel consumption, like other librarys or something outside android completely?
Apologies if this question is a bit chaotic, I haven't been here in a while.
Thanks in advance

"Is there really no way at all to do this without?" -- use an emulator for smaller changes.

Well my primary concern with this app lies in the connectibility with my car, so an emulator doesn't really show if reading data works as it should. Or would an emulator simulate sensor data and alike too?

"Or would an emulator simulate sensor data and alike too?" -- yes, at least for some properties. This emulator is for Android Automotive, but as far as I know it can also be used for testing Android Auto apps. Note that "every little test of every small change" does not necessarily imply changes to "the connectibility with my car". For example, changes to your app's UI might be tested just using the emulator.

For Android Auto, you can simulate hardware information locally using the Desktop Head Unit (DHU) - https://developer.android.com/training/cars/testing/dhu#sensors
